# How to route all traffic from a specific port to a specific network interface?

Tags: ssh, iptables, ip, route

I have the following setup:

A computer with two network cards connected to two different routers. The first router redirects all outside traffic coming on port 5122 to port 22. So that I can connect to the machine using ssh.

I wish to use the first router only for ssh connections. Nothing else. So I want all other traffic directed through the second router.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean incoming traffic to port 22 or what exactly do you mean? If you mean incoming traffic to port 22, that is already done with the redirect rule in your router.

Comment: I worded the post quite awkwardly, I've edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Like this:***

**1. Mark packets**

Set a mark on each packet which is heading for port 5122.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --dport 5122 \
  -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Alternatively like this if you want to limit it to packets with a destination ip of 10.10.10.10:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp -d 10.10.10.10/32 --dport 5122 \
  -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

**2. Create routing table/rule**

Create routing table with a rule for it to be used for the marked packets.

```
echo 201 ssh5122.out >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 1 table ssh5122.out
```

**3. Add the route**

Add the route corresponding to the routing table.

```
ip route add default via $ssh_router_ip dev $ssh_router_interface \
  dev table ssh5122.out
```

That should work.

Comment: Thank you! Ended up going with a more simpler solution but I will try that next time, marking each packet didn't occur to me. Very elegant.

Comment: @user4338027 how did you do it?

Comment: I decided that I really don't need that setup, and connecting just one router to the machine is enough. So not really a solution I guess.